# In msysGit ssh.exe and ssh-keygen.exe crash

Tags: windows-7, msysgit

I installed msysGit 1.7.7.1 (full installer) on windows 7. When I try to run `ssh` (or `ssh-keygen`), I get a (Windows) window error message saying that "*ssh.exe has stopped working*". When I use other commands such as `ping` they work fine.

Why does it stop?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us a lot to go on.

It could be anything from a failing hard drive to a misconfigured setup script.

If msysgit was compiled on your computer, you very likely have things compiled incorrectly.

Comment: Msys is the name of a linux to windows bash emulation. A lot of things can go wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

First, uninstall your **msysGit** and then Install "Git-1.9.5-preview20150319.exe" under download section on **[this link](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/)** (Whatever version of Git is showing at very first option)

It simply worked for me, after hours of struggle. :)